# how to avoid jackson escaping backslash?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I set `"this\'s my case!"` to an object's field.

Calling `writeAsString`, output is `"this\\\'s my case!"`.

But I expect `"this\'s my case!"`.

How can I get what I want ?

```
public class CommonUtils {
    public static ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    public static ObjectMapper getObjectMapperInstance(){
        return objectMapper;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        CommonUtils commonUtils = new CommonUtils();
        commonUtils.test();
    }
    public void test() throws IOException {
        List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
        String xx = "page://list?params={\"city\"}";
        list.add(new MyObject(1,xx));
    }
    class MyObject{

        public MyObject(int tag,String str){
            this.tag = tag;
            this.str = str;
        }
        int tag;
        String str;

        public int getTag() {
            return tag;
        }

        public void setTag(int tag) {
            this.tag = tag;
        }

        public String getStr() {
            return str;
        }

        public void setStr(String str) {
            this.str = str;
        }
    }
}
```

Output of above code:

[ {
  "tag" : 1,
  "str" : "page://list?params={\\"city\\"}]

What I want is:
[ {
  "tag" : 1,
  "str" : "page://list?params={\"city\"}]

Comment: what is the problem with the output you got.I didn't get

Answer (score 0):

If you Change the String xx to

```
String xx = "page://list?params={\\\"city\\\"}"; //page://list?params={\"city\"}
```

You will get desired result;

```
[ { "tag" : 1, "str" : "page://list?params={\"city\"}]
```

Comment: Thanks. But I do not accept that way. Is there any configuration of jackson  to handle this case ?

Comment: What output you want then?